# Where can I see how many approved edits are left to gain reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

We all know that you can get 1000 reputation by editing posts while you are below 2k reputation.

Is there any way to keep track of these? Is the number "post edited" in the profile connected to it and does it shows the accurate number? So if I have 100 posts edited, which would be 200 reputation, are 400 left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find 3 different numbers in your profile (StackOverflow):

- The number is the number of posts edited in the impact block,
  directly above the number of helpful flags. In your case it is 116
  currently. This is the number of approved suggestions. (Maybe a bit too low due to caching, but that is not significant.)
- The number of suggestions is currently 126. This is approved+rejected+pending suggestions.
- The number of revisions is currently 142 for you. This are approved suggestions+self-edits.

Only the first category counts towards the 1000 reputation, because that is the only category you get +2 from. This is also the only category counting towards badges such as Strunk&White and Copy Editor.

You get 1000 rep form edits, so that is 500 times +2 in total. You are quite unlikely to hit that limit though, since you can still get 768 rep form edits and its only 616 rep until you hit 2000.

Comment: Yeah I expected that while I was calculating my "high" voted ansers. Damn, startet too late too edit :/ but thank you for your detailed answer

Comment: @bish You don't have to complete that 1,000 rep from edits. Also, you can always dive into tag edits; they can gain you 2 rep until you reach 20k rep.

Answer (score 11):

Go to [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and at the bottom is a line printing your reputation gained so far from suggested edits.

For example, on my /reputation page on Stack Overflow…

> earned 936 reputation from suggested edits

Thus, (1000-936)/2=32 edits remaining.

Comment: You posted your own number of edits remaining, did you realize that?

Comment: @wythagoras Yes, one cannot access other user's /reputation page.

Comment: I think this is better, as it might have confused the OP about how many edits he had left. +1

Comment: @wythagoras I upvoted yours too, but IMO yours is more useful for looking at other users as it requires a bit more calculation.

Comment: @grgarside Didn't know about that hidden page :O wythagoras No problem about posting his number - at least I was not confused by this

Comment: @grgarside +1 for this hidden page. I just tried on my Meta.SE and it works perfectly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation